# Update a table and insert missing records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table with a foreign key column with some NULL records. I can select the records with missing column such as:

```
SELECT * FROM Outgoing WHERE Receipt_Id IS NULL
```

Now for each of these records I want to insert a new record in the table `Receipts`, get the inserted record's `Id` and set it as the value for `Receipt_Id` in this record.

Is this possible in a query?

Comment: Is there an ID or unique column in the * part of Outgoing table?

Comment: You're affecting multiple tables, so multiple statements must be used.  But it would not be too hard to accomplish.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi yes. Both tables have `Id` as primary key

Comment: @AlirezaNoori then why don't you do Receipt_id =id in the Outgoing table? What I really meant is that did you insert Outgoing.Id into receipts table?

Comment: @DhruvJoshi but I want the `Id` from the `Receipts` table to be in that column, not the `Id` from the `Outgoing` table. Otherwise it wouldn't be a foreign key, right?

Comment: Exactly my point so where do you intend to store Outgoing.Id( as selected in select *) into Receipts tables or will you not store?

Comment: @DhruvJoshi the `Receipts` table only has 1 column named `Id`. I don't use `Outgoing`'s `Id` in the `Receipts` table. But I store `Id` from `Receipts` in the `Outgoing` table. BTW, the `Id` is primary key and auto increment.

Comment: Please post the insert statement.

Comment: @paparazzo `Insert into Receipts default values`. BTW [check this image](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DcTFK90XUAAqpww.jpg:large)

Comment: Really that is your insert statement?   I hope this gets closed.  You have shown little effort.

Comment: @paparazzo what are you talking about? Yes that's the insert. The table has only 1 column and it's Auto Increment. what do you expect?

Comment: You have a select statement with a *.  What possible purpose is a Receipts table with only 1 column.  Why would you ever need a foreign key when there is no data to get?

Comment: @paparazzo The `Receipts` table only has 1 column. But the `Outgoing` table has multiple. As for 
the reason, it's because I want a unique number for multiple records so in my application I use that table to generate unique numbers.

Comment: Talk about XY problem.  This is so messed up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for `inserted` table

```
INSERT INTO Receipts (col1, col2....)
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
INTO @CreatedIds -- TEMP TABLE WHICH HOLDS RECENTLY INERTED DATA INCLUDING Receipt_Id (pk)
SELECT col1, col2.... 
FROM Outgoing 
WHERE Receipt_Id IS NULL
```

To, see recently inserted records

```
SELECT c.*
FROM @CreatedIds c -- Note this is a table variable that you need to manual create.
```

Comment: Sorry unless I'm missing something, in your statement there's an `Insert` and `Select` where does it use the inserted Id and updates the records. Shouldn't there be a `Update` statement?

Comment: You have the inserted ID in @CreatedIds.  Use it in an update statement.

Comment: Well I can't figure out which update statement to use. That's the main part of the question to be honest

Comment: You did not post the insert statement like I asked.  You did not post the table definition.  This is not a coding service where we guess what you need.

Comment: @paparazzo sorry for the delay. didn't see it. Commented.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Since you are using Receipt table only as a sequence table. You should follow the updated approach which uses Sequences

**Updated Answer:**

All you need to do is to create a sequence say Receipts instead of a table with one column. And then update the Outgoing table with sequence numbers.

```
   --create table Outgoing ( id int Primary Key IDENTITY(1,1),data nvarchar(100), record_id int);
--insert into Outgoing values ('john',NULL),('jane',NULL),('jean',NULL);

create sequence dbo.receipts as int start with 1 increment by 1;

update Outgoing
set record_id= NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.receipts
where record_id is null

select * from Outgoing
```

### <kbd>**[See working demo](http://rextester.com/OCJF65904)**</kbd>

**Old Answer below**

If you have `ID` column in both tables you can update `Receipt_Id` based on this column back into the `Outgoing` table

So you steps are :
1. insert records

```
DECLARE @LastRID bigint 
SELECT @LastRID= MAX(Id) FROM Receipts
INSERT INTO Receipts(<col list>)
SELECT <col list> FROM Outgoing WHERE Receipt_Id IS NULL
```

update records based on uniqueness of all columns inserted from Outgoing to receipts using [`CHECKSUM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function

```
update O
set O.Receipt_Id=R.Id
From Outgoing  O
Join Receipts R 
on CHECKSUM(o.<col list>)=CHECKSUM(R.<col list>)
and R.Id>@LastRID
```

Comment: Running this it says cannot insert explicit value when `IDENTITY_INSERT` is set to `OFF`.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori That happens when you try to insert into an IDENTITY column. I suspect that your `col list` is not correct in the  part `INSERT INTO Receipts(<col list>)
SELECT <col list> FROM Outgoing WHERE Receipt_Id IS NULL`

Comment: @AlirezaNoori At this part, you'd need to show me what you substituted for `Col list`?

Comment: I just use one column. `Id`

Comment: I just set it to ON but unfortunately there's a problem. Some of the rows create duplicate value for the Id on the Receipts table.

Comment: Are you saying that you ran INSERT INTO Receipts(id) SELECT id FROM Outgoing WHERE Receipt_Id IS NULL

Comment: Here's the full query. Hope it formats OK.

```SET IDENTITY_INSERT Receipts ON

DECLARE @LastRID bigint SELECT @LastRID= MAX(Id) 
FROM Receipts

 INSERT INTO Receipts(Id)
SELECT Id FROM Outgoing 
WHERE Receipt_Id IS NULL 

update O
set O.Receipt_Id=R.Id
From Outgoing  O
Join Receipts R 
on CHECKSUM(o.Id)=CHECKSUM(R.Id)
and R.Id>@LastRID


SET IDENTITY_INSERT Receipts OFF
```

Comment: In your posted question is ID the only column that constitutes the * part of query 'SELECT * FROM Outgoing WHERE Receipt_Id is NULL'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172995/discussion-between-alireza-noori-and-dhruvjoshi).